# Bypass system proxy settings in PowerShell HTTP GET

Tags: .net, powershell, http, proxy, webclient

I have script to GET HTTP content and I need bypass proxy (connect directly to webserver IP).

Is it possible without changing registry in Windows? This code is going through proxy defined in system.

Thanks for advice
Best regards.

```
$url='https://10.10.10.10/check';
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient;
$output = $webClient.DownloadString($url)
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy.aspx) you have to set the proxy to a blank proxy instance. Try this:

```
$url = "https://10.10.10.10/check"
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Proxy = [System.Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()
$output = $webClient.DownloadString($url)
```